# Installing topojson on OSX Mavericks with node npm

Tags: node.js, npm, osx-mavericks, topojson

I cannot get topojson to install on Mavericks via node npm (using sudo). I have Xcode command-line tools installed and have tried various solutions but no luck. Here is my output:

```
> contextify@0.1.6 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson/node_modules/d3/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/contextify/src/contextify.o
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-arch"
make: *** [Release/obj.target/contextify/src/contextify.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson/node_modules/d3/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.24
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! not ok
    ....
    npm ERR! contextify@0.1.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls contextify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
    ....
npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "topojson"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/mattmosier
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    ....
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mattmosier/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up discovering the problem was two-fold.

1) My version of the gcc compiler was old. I was using 4.5 when the latest available is 4.9. I updated this (with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)) and thought I would be in the clear. Nope.

2) I ran `which gcc` and discovered it was still pointing to an older version I loaded with Macports. Therefore, neither the newer version of gcc nor the Xcode command line tools were being used (Macports dropped everything into `/opt/local/bin`, instead of `/usr/local/bin`). I corrected the problem by removing the `/opt/local/bin` and `/opt/local/sbin` from my `$PATH`. After that, `sudo npm install -g topojson` worked great.

Comment: Thank you - I was running into a similar problem and your answer led me to try updating gcc, which solved the problem for me.